# How do I rebase a list of commits?

Tags: git, rebase

Say I have the commits

- `bb8d6cc3c7`
- `aa213lk321`
- `f0j9123r9j`

I want to do an interactive rebase for each of them. The only way I can think of doing this is typing `git rebase -i 'commit_hash'` for each commit and doing the rebases one by one.

Is there an easier way to rebase all at once, smt. like

`git rebase -i 'commit_hash_1' 'commit_hash_2' 'commit_hash_3'` ?

Comment: `git rebase` works with ranges of consecutive commits. If your commits are not consecutive then the command you are looking for is [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: Does you version of git use non-hex characters in commit hashes or is this just an example?

Answer (score 4):

This is the list of the commits you want to squash.

```
1. bb8d6cc3c7 <- This is the HEAD or latest commit
2. aa213lk321
3. f0j9123r9j
```

**Command**

`git rebase -i HEAD~3` , if all above three commits in sequence

then you need to `pick bb8d6cc3c7` and squash other two commits by entering `s`, it means squash.

if the commit is not in sequence then just do `git rebase -i` , this will open an editor and you pick one commit and squash other two commits on it.

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: This answer depends on capabilities of the text-editor opened by git rebase.  I'm using vim for which it works.*

Say we have a range of commits in branch `my-branch` on top of a revision (i.e. branch or tag) named `my-branch-base`.

- a8d737b50 (`my-branch`)
- **bb8d6cc3c7**
- 79a2e5cc5
- fec125378
- 193cf566b
- **aa213lk321**
- **f0j9123r9j**
- ea781de38
- 61785bd55
- 04428cafd (`my-branch-base`)

In this range there are some commits to edit:

- bb8d6cc3c7
- aa213lk321
- f0j9123r9j

*Perhaps they come from a file perhaps they come from a command (such as `git log -G"MyFunction"`).  I'll show how to select them via a command.*

Make a copy of your branch HEAD pre rebase
*(because: you will have a backup in case your rebase does not work out as you intended; and, if you select commits to edit via `git log`, git needs a reference to them during the rebase)*:

```
git branch -c my-branch my-branch-prerebase
```

Then start the rebase:

```
git rebase --interactive my-branch-base
```

Opens your configured editor with:

> pick a8d737b50 *{commit msg}*
> pick bb8d6cc3c7 *{commit msg}*
> pick 79a2e5cc5 *{commit msg}*
> pick fec125378 *{commit msg}*
> pick 193cf566b *{commit msg}*
> pick aa213lk321 *{commit msg}*
> pick f0j9123r9j *{commit msg}*
> pick ea781de38 *{commit msg}*
> pick 61785bd55 *{commit msg}*

Open a second buffer --in the editor started by `git rebase`-- with the output of the revision selection command or a the file with the hashes to edit.
In vim you can do
*(note you need to specify `my-branch-prerebase` to `git log`, since `HEAD` now points to `my-branch-base` and `git log` would not select any applicable commit hashes.)*:

```
:vsplit
:enew
:r !git log --oneline -G"MyFunction" my-branch-prerebase
```

Change the (generated) list of revisions into a format that your editor can use as an expression to select lines to edit.
In vim you can do (in the right window)
*(note: that `\x` selects hex-digits and OP's hashes contain non-hex digits suck as `j` and `k`, so OP might need `\w`; and, in my siuation `git log --oneline` produced 9 digit hash abbreviations, you might need a different length (the made-up example needs `{9,10}`*:

```
:%s/\v(\x{7,9}).*\n/\1|/
```

The `\n` concatenates the lines to a single line.

In vim we copy this to a register and paste it later into the minibuffer via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.

Return to the buffer with rebase actions.  Search and replace 'pick' with 'edit' on the  lines matching the selected commit hashes.
In vim:

```
:g/\vbb8d6cc3c7|aa213lk321|f0j9123r9j/ :s/pick/edit/
```

Save the list of rebase actions and discard the temporary buffer with the selected commit hashes.  Close the editor.  `git rebase` starts rebasing and stops on the marked commits.

Answer (score -1):

Weel, if you have `master` branch and `some-feature` branch.

If someone updates `master` branch and you want to rebase you `some-feature` branch, ...

Just

```
git checkout some-feature
git rebase -i master
```

All the `some-feature`'s commits are merged to master branch

Comment: please, give me motivation of the -1. I use this command every day